# Pagespeed Error in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am currently experiencing a problem in mod_pagespeed and pagespeed.
The image/file does not load due to an additional array after the file name .

- WP-sitename/wp-content/filename.png.**pagespeed.ce.uVV-0JsmxC.png**

  - by following the path name the result is 
    [image]

2 Solutions I tried -

1. clear cache, and re-upload the image file.
   BY checking it the in my Media (WP) the image url is sitename/wp-content/filename.png which is correct.
2. Remove and Deactivated  WP-Fastest-Cache but still not working

---

My site version is currently 4.7.13.

Answer (score -1):

Open CPanel Domain
Cache Manager
Enable or Diable Google